# check values in a multidimensional array at a specific key

Tags: php, html

I am building a portfolio with multiple categories.
I have a multidimensional array…

```
$allProjects = array(
    'project1' => array('corporate', 'web'),
    'project2' => array('corporate', 'print', 'animation'),
    'project3' => array('web')
);
```

and I need to check in that multidimensional array at a specific key (e.g 'project1') if a value exists (e.g. 'web')

so I guess something like this…

```
$project = $_GET('project'); //this is the project that is displayed
$category = 'print' //for example, I would redefine this variable for each category.

foreach ($allProjects as $project => $categories) {
if in_array($category, $project);
echo 'yes';
}
```

I use $project, variable defined above, as key but that doesn't work. All I want is to use the name of the project (defined in $project) as a key for the in_array function and check for appearance of $category in the values.

Thanks for help

Comment: You set `$project` with your `$_GET` and then reassign it in your `foreach` loop. Any reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$project = $_GET['project'];
$category = 'print';

$categories = $allProjects[$project];
if (!empty($categories) && in_array($category, $categories)) {
    echo 'yes';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want doesn't need a loop:

```
<?php
$allProjects = array(
   'project1' => array('corporate', 'web'),
   'project2' => array('corporate', 'print', 'animation'),
   'project3' => array('web')
);

$project = $_GET['project'];
$category = 'print';
if(in_array($category, $allProjects[$project])) {
   echo 'yes';
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried that but… 
1. it says: "Function name must be a string", refering to this line: $project = $_GET('project'); and 
2. it echoes 5 times 'yes' which can only be the number of all the projects with that specific category (in this case: 'print')

Comment: $_GET is an array, not a function. It's used as $_GET['key']. The code from your question also can't actually run, but I would guess the condition is never evaluated so it always prints.